# to capture used space by ansible

Tags: ansible

I have a simple playbook:

tasks:

```
- shell: df -h "{{ item }}" | tail -n 1 | awk {'print $5 '}  | sed 's/%//g'

  with_items:

  - "/"

  register: FS

- debug: var=FS

- debug: var=FS.stdout
```

from:     debug: var=FS    I have a lot of lines but at the bottom I still can see 2 lines with the size

from:    debug: var=FS.stdout    or   FS.result      I got:   "FS.result": "VARIABLE IS NOT DEFINED!"

how I can get the output with the number only  ?

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

> how I can get the output with the number only ?

Had you looked closer at the output of `var=FS` you would have observed that ansible actually captures the results of **all** the loop items, which applies to you due to the use of `with_items:`

Thus, your answer is two fold: if you really want just the df of **one** item, don't use a `with_items` and the result will be in `FS.stdout` just as you tried. If you want the `df` of multiple items, then you'll need to reach into the `.results[]` list and extract the `stdout` from each one:

```
- debug:
    msg: '{{ FS.results | map(attribute="stdout") | list }}'
```

although that presumes that you kept the list which was fed into `with_items:` around, since the `results` list is ordered in the same way.

If, on the other hand, you'd prefer to create a `dict[str, str]` mapping from the original list item to its result:

```
- debug: var=free_by_mount_point
  vars:
    free_by_mount_point: >-
      {%- set results = {} -%}
      {%- for r in FS.results -%}
      {%-   set _ = results.update({r.item, r.stdout}) -%}
      {%- endfor -%}
      {{ results }}
```

Comment: still getting the error:

I have in my playbook now:

    - shell: df -h / | tail -n 1 | awk {'print $5 '}  | sed 's/%//g'

      register: FS

    - debug: var="{{ FS.results|map(attribute='stdout')|list }}"




when I run it I have the error:

FAILED! => {"msg": "The task includes an option with an undefined variable. 
The error was: 'dict object' has no attribute 'results'\n\nThe error appears to be in '/var/tmp/emp0001/ansible/disk-full-4.yml': line 27, column 7, 
but may\nbe elsewhere in the file depending on the exact syntax problem.\n\nThe offending line appears to be:\

Comment: As I said in the very first sentence, things that use `with_items:` (or any `loop` construct) have a `results` list, but if you don't use looping, then you don't need the `map`. In that sample that you posted in the comment, without the `with_items`, it is in `FS.stdout` and that information was available to you via `- debug: var=FS`

Comment: I changed my script and I do not use items now,

so I use only 1 command:

 - shell: df -h / | tail -n 1 | awk {'print $5 '}  | sed 's/%//g'

   register: FS
 
 - debug: var=FS.stdout


but it gives me stdout with number, how I can get the number only ?

Comment: the reason I need to get the number only   is:   then I can do:      when:  number >= 90       display it and send the email or page us